# QGIS _Distance from point to polygon- doubt

Tags: qgis, distance, mmqgis

I want to calculate the distance between a shp of points and a shp with a few polygons.
I am using MMQGIS (Hub distances), a UTM coordinate system, and everything works fine, but I think it is giving me the distance from each point to the center of each polygon and, since the shp of the polygon represents water courses, I would like to obtain the distance of each point to the "surface" of the polygon.

Because there are points very close to the water but the distance I obtain is very far way.

Here:
[image]

The yellow polygon represents almost the whole river, and there are points very cloe to the river but the distance I obtain is, for instance, 5 km.

How do I do solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that it calculates the distance between your points to the centroid of polygons/lines. You could:

1. Convert your polygon to lines (`Vector > Geometry Tools > Polygons to Lines`)
2. Convert your lines to points (`Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Shapes - Points > Convert Lines to Points`)
3. Then run the `Hub distances` using your main points layer and the newly converted points layer

---

Or you could try using the GRASS tool **v.distance** (`Processing Toolbox > GRASS commands > Vector > v.distance`)

Comment: I used GRASS and it works very well, thank you very much!

Comment: @Teresa - Most welcome, glad it worked =)